# Update Stripe data-amount

Tags: javascript, jquery, stripe-payments

I'm implementing Stripe into a django website and everything is working except for one part. In my cart, users can update the items which changes the total. Everything is working correctly except for setting the data-amount on the [Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) js script.

When the page loads, everything works great, however if the customer changes their cart, the data-amount does not update. I have another box which shows the total, and that amount updates fine.

```
<!-- here is the script tag in HTML-->
<script
id="stripe-script"
src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" 
class="stripe-button"
data-image="{% static 'img/marketplace.png' %}"
data-key="{{ STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY }}"
data-name="Serendipity Artisan Blends"
data-description="Purchase Items"
data-amount="{{ cart_stripe_total }}">
</script>
```

And then my javascript that attempts to update is this:

```
function updateTotal(amount) {
    /* update the total in the cart in both the table cell and
        in the stripe button data-amount */
    var totalStr = shoppingTotalCell.text().replace('$', ''),
        originalTotal = parseFloat(totalStr),
        newTotal = originalTotal + amount,
        newTotalStripe = newTotal * 100,
        newTotalStr = newTotal.toFixed(2),
        script = $('#stripe-script');

    shoppingTotalCell.text('$' + newTotalStr);

    console.log(script.data("amount"));
    // this returns the correct original amount

    script.data("amount", newTotalStripe);

    console.log(script.data("amount"));
    /* this returns the updated amount, however the HTML data-amount 
        attribute does not update. */
  }
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Turns out that to have a dynamic data-amount for the stripe payment, you have to use [Custom Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom) instead of Simple Checkout. This code did the trick.

```
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="stripe-button">
        Checkout <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
      </button>

      <script>
        $('#stripe-button').click(function(){
          var token = function(res){
            var $id = $('<input type=hidden name=stripeToken />').val(res.id);
            var $email = $('<input type=hidden name=stripeEmail />').val(res.email);
            $('form').append($id).append($email).submit();
          };

          var amount = $("#stripeAmount").val();
          StripeCheckout.open({
            key:         '{{ STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY }}',
            amount:      amount,
            name:        'Serendipity Artisan Blends',
            image:       '{% static "img/marketplace.png" %}',
            description: 'Purchase Products',
            panelLabel:  'Checkout',
            token:       token
          });

          return false;
        });
      </script>
```

Answer (score 5):

OR you can just use the following code before clicking the stripe button ;-)

```
StripeCheckout.__app.configurations.button0.amount = 1234;

$('#stripe-button').click();
```

Comment: This is not secure at all, you could change the amount manually on the client side to pay 0.

Answer (score 2):

As @awwester said, you can use Stripe's Custom Checkouts.  Although, I found an easier way to do this through jQuery simply by remounting the script with the changed variable each time they increase the quantity:

```
$("#stripe-form").html(
  '<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="' +
    totalCost.replace(".", "") +
    '" /><input type="hidden" name="currency" value="usd" /><script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button" data-key="pk_test_123123123123" data-amount="' +
    totalCost.replace(".", "") +
    '" data-zip-code="true" data-currency="usd" data-billing-address="true" data-shipping-address="true" data-name="Company Name" data-description="Product Name" data-image="https://image" data-locale="auto"></script>'
);
```